# Random number generation always returns same value

Tags: java, sockets, client, server, port

I am trying to run a simple program where server listens for connections, receives a client request and sends a message. Perhaps trivial, but my confusion is regarding the behavior of server. The code is as follows:

Server code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class haikuServer {

    private static String chooseHaiku() {
        String[] haiku = new String[3];
        haiku[0] = "Pawprints disappear"+"\n"+"into the snowy glen, but"+"\n"+"fox waits patiently.";
        haiku[1] = "Whispering winds cry"+"\n"+"while frenzied snowflakes scatter,"+"\n"+"searching for others.";
        haiku[2] = "The path, hard and long"+"\n"+"brings dawn with passage of time"+"\n"+"and then my heart sings.";

        Random t = new Random();
        int ch = t.nextInt(3); 
        return haiku[ch];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(5575);

            while (true) {
                Socket client = sock.accept();

                PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

                String haiku = chooseHaiku();
                pout.println(haiku);
                client.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class haikuClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5575);

            InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            System.out.println("\nHaiku:\n");
            String line;
            while ((line = bin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println();

            /* Close the socket connection */
            sock.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine. I compile both the files. To run them, I use: java haikuServer & (& to run the program in background) and then haikuClient. My problem is that I try to run haikuClient multiple times but all the times, the choice picked up by server is the first one, i.e., haiku[0] and not the others. Why is that so?

Comment: never silently swallow exceptions `catch (Exception e) {}`

Comment: so you question has go nothing to do with sockets, but rather why doesn't random work as you expect - right.

Comment: As I also mentioned in the answer below, perhaps I am again making some mistake, but I tried running the client more than 10 times and still get only the first one.

Comment: keep your question short. others won't spend time answering you if you include too much unrelated bits.

Comment: Also, the haiku are boring:)

Comment: My request is sent, bytes scattered on the routers, still no sodding reply:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the networking, but everything to do with the random number generation.

Your observation that only the first item in the array is ever returned is incorrect... when I run your code it alternates between the first two elements in the array.

The documentation for `nextInt` states this:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

so this call: `nextInt(2)` returns a digit between 0 and 1. If you run the client enough times you will see the Haiku returned alternating between the first and second in the array. To get any of three random elements you want to use `nextInt(3)`.

Comment: For not using nextInt(3), my bad. I may be going wrong somewhere again, but I still get only the first array element in response - I tried more than 10 times and still the same, in fact, that is why I mentioned even the way I compiled and ran the programs.

Comment: And yes, the question is not related to networking. But still I chose such a title and tags is because I thought that someone with the knowledge would only like to go through this. But again, I am a newbie with all this, so perhaps I am over-assuming.

Comment: @Neha That is not the result I'm seeing - I get a mix of the two first if I leave the server process running and run the client multiple times. Are you sure you are running the correct version of the code?

Comment: Yes, definitely. The first time that you pointed out, I double checked. Infact, when I first saw the problem, I just wrote a code to check if the random number generator works fine. It did. And therefore, I thought I could be missing something somewhere else. However, if you say you are getting it right, I'll better show it to someone in person and get it right. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help! :)